# What happens if I delete a profile in apparmor

Tags: apparmor

I would like to what happens a program if the apparmor profile associated with it is deleted.  Would it run as if it had unconstrained access?

Answer (score 0):

It would run as if it had unconfigured access. Meaning, it would use whatever defaults are set for your system. If you plan on doing that, I would highly suggest making a backup though... Those are there for a reason.